# MongoDB shell query selector?

Tags: mongodb

Would this query only return the document that satisfies both keys, or is it going to display those containing just one as well?

```
db.collection.findOne ( {price : 1, age : 1} )
```

How is the empty query selector parameter going to reflect on the results?

```
db.collection.findOne ( {}, {price : 1, age : 1} )
```

Comment: first {} in find() is your query, for example findOne({ {price : 100, age : 30} }) means search for document with price = 100 and age = 30, the second {} is for filtering your result, {price : 1, age : 1} just show price and age fields in your output

Comment: So, the query is more specific, and the the projection is just going to display the documents, that have those keys in them?

Comment: Spend some time reading over the documentation to get a basic understanding of MongoDB querying concepts: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations-introduction/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `db.collection.findOne(<criteria>, <projection>)`:

### Criteria parameter

This query will return the *first* document that satisfies **both** the following conditions, being `age==15` and `price==0.5`:

```
db.collection.findOne( {price : 0.5, age : 15} )
```

### Projection parameter

The projection parameter defines the fields you want to show up in the response. You can include a parameter (giving it a value of `1` or `true` in your query) or exclude a parameter (giving it a value of `0` or `false` in your query).

So the query:

```
db.collection.findOne ( {}, {price : 1, age : 1} )
```

will return the very first item of your collection (query by `{}`), showing only the `price` and the `age` fields.

For reference, see [the fine manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/).

Answer (score 0):

1) This query `db.collection.findOne ( {price : 1, age : 1} )` will return documents which satisfies both keys `price equals 1 AND age equals 1` 
If you want to use OR matching than use this syntax:

```
db.collection.findOne ( {
  $or: [
     { name: 1 },
     { age: 1 }
  ]
}
```

2) The second parameter for findOne is projection. According to documentation

```
One document that satisfies the criteria specified as the first argument to this method. 
If you specify a projection parameter, findOne() returns a document that only contains the
projection fields. The _id field is always included unless you explicitly exclude it.
```

It means if you use the second parameter it will return only fields matched in this parameter

```
db.collection.findOne({ name: 1, age: 1 }, { name: 1 })
```

It will return documents containing only `_id` and `name` fields, which satisfy name and age

Comment: What's the point of specifying my search criteria twice? What is a "cursor" in Mongo?

Comment: @nosille the second parameters it's not a search criteria, it's an additional parameters, which specify the output format of documents. 
You can limit the output fields to ones you will need in your code. 
Example: Your task is to output 10000 names, so you don't need an age in this task. It will take an overhead in this case unless you specify only the ```name``` field. So best practice in this case is to limit the output fields with projection.

Comment: can you do nested properties where you have name and age?